# custom shouldInterceptRequest() does not load javascript on webview in android (jelly bean)

Tags: java, android, webview, webviewclient

I use following code only for `Android jelly bean(4.1, 4.2, 4.3)`
I override the `shouldInterceptRequest()` inside the `webViewclient`

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String sourceurl) {
     try {

         URL url = new URL(sourceurl);

         HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

         //make https connection using tls
         SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
         sslcontext.init(null, null, null);
         SSLSocketFactory noSSLv3Factory = null;

         noSSLv3Factory = new TLSSocketFactory();
         urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(noSSLv3Factory);

         String responseEncoding = urlConnection.getContentEncoding();
         String responseMimeType = urlConnection.getContentType();
         return new WebResourceResponse(responseMimeType, responseEncoding, urlConnection.getInputStream());

    } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I used [TLSSocketFactory](https://gist.github.com/fkrauthan/ac8624466a4dee4fd02f#file-tlssocketfactory-java) class for create TLS enabled socket to HttpsURLConnection request. It works fine.

Now the webview displays my website but it does not load any js file in the website. So many events do not occur in my web page. Then when I run my app, it gives following error:

```
E/Web Console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL at https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js:1

E/Web Console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL at https://mytestsite.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:1
```

All java script files are not loaded with the same error message.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?